# Sponsor logo twenty eleven

Tags: php, wordpress, graphical-logo

I am using Wordpress with the Twenty Eleven theme.

At the moment I have the emblem of a sports club inlined with the header. I have now been asked to add a sponsor's logo left of the header inline with the emblem. Does anyone know of a easy way of accomplishing this?

here is the code:

```
<header id="branding" role="banner">
        <hgroup>
            <h1 id="site-title"><img  src="http://aberdeenshirecc.org.uk/phpHrX1SaAM.jpg"style="width:84px;height:100px; display:inline; vertical-align:center; img margin-top:200px; "<span><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></span></h1>



 Sponsored by:
<img  src="http://aberdeenshirecc.org.uk/Ace.jpg"style="width:200px;height:76px;    float:left; display:inline; vertical-align:left; ">
            <h2 id="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
        </hgroup>
```

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: Okay, added some code.

Comment: Create a new image in Photoshop (or whatever program you use) and drop it right in. No code required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a div with your image in it and position it using css:

CSS:

```
#imgdiv {
 position:absolute;
 top:20px;
 left:-40px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class='imgdiv'><img src='myimage.jpg' /></div>
```

Note: You will need to tweak the values of 'top' and 'left' to get it to appear where you need it.